# Heapsort strategy: based on selection or interchange?

Tags: algorithm, heapsort

I cannot decide what approach would be more appropriate to HeapSort. The fact that selects the root or that it changes it with the last element? What from these two would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these lecture notes](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Eftang/courses/CS241/notes/sorting.htm#:%7E:text=Heapsort%20is%20a%20comparison%2Dbased,(n%20log%20n)%20runtime.)

> Heapsort is a comparison-based sorting algorithm, and is part of the selection sort family.
>
> Heapsort is similar to selection sort in that it locates the largest value and places it in the final array position.

So based on selection seems to be correct.

Comment: That is true when you only look at the first element, after that I would think it more like an interchange as it interchanges more than on value to keep the heap invariant.

Comment: @Surt restoring the heap property via a series of exchanges is just one possible way to do it, and not even the best way. It's comparable to rotating an array by one position via a series of swaps, except here the array is not contiguous and it's the path from the root to the final position of the old root value. There is an equivalent series of *moves* (rather than swaps) that costs about half the number of operations.